# In ketosis, does ketone production comes from stored fat or eaten fat?

Tags: weight-loss, burn-fat, ketogenic-diet

I'm wondering once you are in Ketosis, what is the fuel used to produce the ketones: stored body fat or the fat I eat in the meals? Or both?

Comment: Please, one question per question. I'm going to edit to keep this on topic with the title.

Comment: You might want to start here with this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid_metabolism#Dietary_sources_of_fatty_acids.2C_their_digestion.2C_absorption.2C_transport_in_the_blood_and_storage

Answer (score -1):

I have seen a video by science research program BBC Horizon that say ketosis doesn't actually make you lose weight. You can watch it at https://youtu.be/NfsWuvh3eAY?t=28m20s

It answers the question with the answer ketosis is a placebo.

Comment: What a ketogenic diet did for me was basically make me feel full all the time. I even forgot to eat some meals. And you cut out bad carbs. It essentially just makes it easy for you to have a calorie deficit.

Comment: I'm currently in ketosis, and I feel like you say, it might be placebo effect, though. It would be a bomb if Summer were right, I really love eat rice (asian here).

Comment: Interesting video but it doesn't answer the question.